# ways to add fields to user object

Tags: user-record

I want to add 10 fields to user object. Shall I add it to User object directly or shall I first create child object of the user object and then add those fields to it?
Which one is best approach? any thought?

Comment: Any reasons why don't to add it to User object directly?

Comment: @mast0r I am looking for pros and cons of each approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the fields that you need to add have a direct 1:1 relationship with any given user, I would say add them to the User object directly and possibly create a new Section on the page layout to house them.

The other thing to consider is that you can't have the User as the Master in a Master/Detail relationship you can only specify a lookup. If you create a lookup from your 'child' object to User, I don't think you'll then be able to see those records as a related list on your User record as you might expect on other objects.

You could however create a lookup from User to a new object which would then allow you to access the object from the link on the User object or in apex via the Relationshipname__r.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create these fields on User object directly so that you can also access User objects properties/fields as well along with your fields.